# Using REST GET in WCF as 2nd endpoint

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, soap

I trying to add 2nd endpoint in existing WCF Application and my REST method doesn't work.
I created new Interface

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IRestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "RestURI", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string SomeMethod();
}
```

And implemented it in existing service

```
public string SomeMethodImplementation()
    {
        //some logic
    }
```

I'm trying to access this method using basicaddress/service/RestURI but getting 400 Bad Request response.

After that I added protocolMapping, 2nd endpoint and endpoint behavior to config file but it didn't help.

Right now my config file looks like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<protocolMapping>
  <add scheme="http" binding="webHttpBinding"/>
</protocolMapping>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="servicename">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IRestService" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ISoapService"/>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="16348" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I'm not getting any 400 anymore but instead of that 'cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.' error appeared. Also after adding protocolMapping, my soap methods have disappeared when I open wsdl in browser. Without it my rest method can be seen in the list like this:

```
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IRestService" binding="i0:BasicHttpBinding_IRestService">
```

After that I added AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any) in attributes of my Service but it doesn't help.

I found a lot of answers here but somehow not a single one help me to resolve this problem.
What did I miss?

Comment: There are three links at following posting.  Let me know if you have any questions. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d7495c95-dad9-4bcf-8e89-2896ec4b7244/facing-addressfilter-mismatch-error-while-accessing-wcf-service?forum=wcf

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution after I installed WCF for visual studio. All this time I had wrong namespaces in my web.config and had no idea but VS marked it after installing module. I added right namespace and problem went away. I really suggest to install WCF in VS.

Answer (score 0):

The issue boils down to the fact that we fail to host the service in Restful style. 
Ordinarily, there are two ways to configure the Restful style service created by Webhttpbinding.

1.Using the service section to configure the interface and implementation.

```
  <services>
          <service name="WcfService3.Service1">
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService3.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="rest"></endpoint>
          </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="rest">
              <webHttp />
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

There are two points we should pay attention to. In the service section, we are supposed to use the corresponding interface and implementation.

```
  <service name="WcfService3.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService3.IService1"
```

Adding a webhttp endpoint behavior also is essential then apply it by using Behaviorconfiguration property.

```
behaviorConfiguration="mybinding"
```

2. In the latest feature, we could create a WCF Restful style service with protocol mapping.

   ```
      <endpointBehaviors>
       <behavior>
         <webHttp />
       </behavior>
     </endpointBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
   <protocolMapping>
     <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
   ```

It should be noted that we need to add an endpoint behavior without a name.
Based on your configuration, since you have multiple interfaces I suggest you remove the service section and host the service with a protocol mapping feature.
1.  Remove service section in the configuration.
2.  Remove the name of the endpoint behavior.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<protocolMapping>
  <add scheme="http" binding="webHttpBinding"/>
</protocolMapping>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Then we could access the service by the below Uri.

> basicaddress/service.svc/RestURI

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.